# Pasar parámetros de una función para un addEventListener

Tags: javascript, css, html5

es que estoy colocando dos parámetros en una función y cada parámetro activa cada alerta según el condicional lo que no logro hacer es llamar esos parámetros al addEventListener espero que puedan ayudarme con una solución muchas gracias

```js
function changeColor(title1, title2) {
    var titleh = document.querySelector(".title-color");
    var titleChange = document.querySelector(".cambiar");

    if (title1 == "hola") {
        alert("hola");
    } else if (title2 == "hello") {
        alert("hola 2");
    }
}
```

```
**segunda función activa los eventos**
```

```js
window.onload = function actionChange() {
    document.getElementById("cambiar").addEventListener("click", function() {
        changeColor();
    });
    document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function() {
        changeColor();
    })
}
```

Comment: Tu problema no está muy claro, hay muchas variables que no veo dónde las estas usando. Por otra parte, sería bueno colocar el código html.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas con tu código:

1. La función `changeColor` espera recibir dos parámetros y no los estás enviando
2. En lugar de verificar los parámetros, buscas los valores en elementos HTML y no haces nada con esas variables
3. En el `if` estás comparando dos variables no definidas, porque no envías parámetros a la función y, de hecho, no debería aparecer ninguna alerta

Para solucionarlo:

1. Modifica la función para recibir el evento como parámetro, de ahí puedes acceder al elemento que recibió clic y analizar su contenido
2. Cambia la forma de asignar eventos para poner solo el nombre de la función, sin paréntesis, sin función anónima; así aseguras que el evento se envía como parámetro

```js
// Recibe el evento como parámetro
function changeColor(e) {
    // Desde el evento accedes al botón que lo disparó con e.currentTarget
    let btn = e.currentTarget;
    // Tomas el texto del botón
    let title = btn.textContent;

    // Comparas
    if (title == 'Hola') {
        console.log('Hola');
    } else {
        // No es necesario otra comparación, solo hay dos botones
        console.log('Hola 2');
    }
}

// Ejecutar cuando se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Asigna función por nombre, sin paréntesis
    document.getElementById("cambiar").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
    document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", changeColor)
});
```

```html
<button id="cambiar">Hola</button>
<button id="change">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, lo que quieres es pasar parámetros al función que maneja el evento. Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras. Por ejemplo:

```
function foo(custom,otro, event){
  console.log(event)
  console.log(custom)
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", foo.bind(this, "hola", "otro"));
```

Otra es usando tu función dentro del callback

```
function foo(custom,otro, event){
  console.log(event)
  console.log(custom)
}


document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  foo("hola", "otro", event)
});
```